# Baking a particle system in Blender to use in Unity

Tags: export, particles, unity

I am using Blender(2.77a) and Cycles render.

I have a particle system set up in Blender which emits 3D Blood cells. Now, Unity's inbuilt particle system is different from Blender's. So exporting a particle system made in blender to unity is not possible.

But I'm in very much need for this to work. I browsed the web and came across a tutorial for baking 3DsMax particles to Unity and hoped it would work with Blender as well.

But no luck there as well. These are the steps I follow,

1. Set up the particle system
2. Save the blend file and enable Disk Cache
3. Click on "Bake all Dynamics"
4. Export as fbx and import in unity.

Where am I going wrong? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4956/convert-particle-system-to-animated-meshes

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Particle System simulations are not supported at all due to the fact that Unity has a completely different solution.

Unity currently imports (from blender)
all nodes with position, rotation and scale. Pivot points and Names are also imported.
Meshes with vertices, polygons, triangles, UVs, and normals.
Bones,
Skinned Meshes, and
Animations

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Guess I will have to do something else