# I want to export my particle system into unity but don't know how

Tags: animation, particles, export

I made a fire. I tried to export with .FBX but the thing is it just come out like the position when I saved. There is no animation or such.

Comment: It's not actually possible to export a particle system into unity.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/59052/61453

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The only known supported format for particles is alembic cache (.abc) which can be loaded as package.
As stated on the unity page, it does support particles and possibly animation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.alembic@2.2/manual/index.html

Whenever possible though try using the native system instead of a loaded cache as this may be far more versatile in various scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the advices.