# Converting hair particles to a mesh while keeping the animation

Tags: animation, export, unity, hair

There's this game that I'm working on, using Unity as the engine and Blender to make the models, animations etc.

After going though a lot of trouble trying to make the hair look like feathers, I stuck trying to export my model as a `.fbx` to Unity.

Only the model and the animation work properly. The feathers don't scale with the model and the rotation is mess inside the engine. I read in many sites that Unity doesn't support the particle system of Blender, so I'm trying to apply the particle modifier, but then I lose the animation. The feathers are not connected to the mesh, is a scalp with the same animation of the body.

If anyone even understands the problem I'm trying to express with my low-level English, I would be grateful for any help.

[image: Trouble with Feathers]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4956/convert-particle-system-to-animated-meshes

Comment: @Brenticus it's not related because it explains how to export animated meshes which can be done in multiple ways, but this question asks how to export animation of hair