# Baking particle systems to objects in blender 2.80

Tags: animation, particles, baking

I'm trying to bake a particle system with location and scaling data to real objects. I tried to use the script from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4956/convert-particle-system-to-animated-meshes?answertab=active#tab-top) to create real objects an keyframe them according to the particles, but after analyzing why the script didn't work for me I found out that bpy.context.object.particle_systems[0].particles is empty. This is confusing because when printing the name of the particle system it gives the correct name and I have particles in the viewport. Does anyone have an idea what coulb be going wrong?

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html?highlight=particles#bpy.types.ParticleSystem.particles