# export particle mesh to unreal engine 4

Tags: particles, unreal-engine

Does anyone know a way to export a particle mesh animation to unreal engine using alembic for example. Or perhaps a way to bake it to a fbx animation. [image: particles using a cube]

I know you can convert the particles into a mesh but you loose the animation data of the particles when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way here [Convert particle system to animated meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4956/convert-particle-system-to-animated-meshes)

This solution is not perfect. The euler rotation of the particles is not captured perfectly and the workflow to export to unreal is a bit tricky and "crashy".

When you export to fbx make sure you only select a single mesh as more than a couple might crash unreal engine on import. But the interesting thing is that there are multiple animations stored. So you can duplicate the mesh in unreal and select a different animation to create a flock of birds for example. It's no where near as good as the blender particle animation but good enough for a variety of applications.

Hopefully someone else can provide a better solution.