# How to clean linear f-curves to keep only peaks/valleys

Tags: fcurves

How to clean f-curves that have linear lines so that the only keyframes that are kept after the cleanse are the peaks and lowest keyframes where the curve's slope changes.

What I have tried:

1. The **Decimate** (ratio) command - after a certain percentage seems to change the keyframes interpolation to not linear and doesn't keep the peaks and valleys but tries to form an arc between the two points.
2. The **Clean Keyframes** command - seems to remove keyframes in a constant interval betweeen keyframes but after a certain threshold it doesn't keep the peaks and valleys.

Is there a way to clean hundreds of objects that have similar animations of their location data? Attached is an image illustrating the keyframes that should not be removed.

[image: clean fcurves keep peaks valleys]

**Context:** these objects are from a particle simulation that had its particles motion converted to keyframes using the script given in this answer: [Convert particle system to animated meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4956/convert-particle-system-to-animated-meshes)

Answer (score 3):

The function Key > Decimate (Allowed change) seems to work pretty well in this task, both with "Error margin" and "Ratio" behaviour.

Comment: +1 ... how could  missed there are two decimations :) Thanks